# how do you tell if resources are being preloaded in browser developer console

Tags: preload, firefox-developer-tools

I am using `<link rel="preload" ...>` technique to make the resources load faster, but I'm not seeing a measurable effect on page load times. I'm not sure if this is because the resources are not actually being preloaded, or for some other reason.

If I'm using Firefox to debug, how do I determine in the Firefox Developer Console whether a resource was preloaded?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Preloading resources only has a measurable effect if the `<link rel="preload" ...>` and the actual request of the resource are "far apart" from each other. E.g. if you want to preload a CSS style sheet but have the `<link rel="stylesheet" ...>` right after the `<link rel="preload" ...>`, you probably won't see any difference. It may be different when there is a resource within that stylesheet that you want to preload.

Furthermore, you need to ensure that the syntax of the preload is correct. For the preload to work, you have to specify two more attributes besides `rel`, `href` to define the source to preload and `as` to specify the type of resource.

See the description of [`<link>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/link) and the one for [how to preload content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Preloading_content) on MDN for more info on that.

To check whether preloading has any influence on performance, you should have a look at times and the order of the resources being loaded within the [DevTools Network Monitor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor).

---

You may want to check whether preloading actually works in your browser. Here's a simple test to do so:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="preload" href="image.jpg" as="image" type="image/jpeg"/>
        <script>
        for (var i=0; i < 10000000000; i++) {
            var x = i;
        }
        window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",
            e => document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url(image.jpg)'
        );
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

If preloading is supported, the request for the image should be made before the JavaScript gets executed, i.e. you should see the request for the image immediately after the one for the HTML document is done.

Comment: You mention looking at load order in dev tools. I was wondering if Dev Tools might give some more concrete information, such as verifying that the preload tags are successfully parsed. For example, there is a "Cause" column which can display "stylesheet" etc. I was wondering if that might display "preload".

Comment: The "Cause" column currently doesn't provide that info, unfortunately. I have filed a [feature request for giving more info plus linking to the related element](https://bugzil.la/1300978) some time ago. I have also done some testing now and it looks like Firefox indeed does *not* support preloading yet as of Firefox 68, but it does when you switch on the preference `network.preload` I mentioned earlier. I've updated my answer to reflect that and included the example code I've used for testing.

Answer (score 1):

To know if resources are being preloaded, check the networks tab in devtools. You would see that the request was made for the items that are being preloaded. This is regardless of whether the resources are being used or referenced in the current page or not.

Comment: Also, in the Network tab. You tend to see the preloaded resource higher up in the Waterfall.